# Are two compact Hausdorff spaces homeomorphic if their algebras of continuous functions are isomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, banach-algebras

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two compact Hausdorff spaces and $F\colon C(X) → C(Y)$ is a continuous isomorphism of algebras. Can I say $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

The key words always lead me to other questions. Can anyone give me some reference? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the so-called Gelfand-Kolmogorov theorem. It says:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact, Hausdorff spaces. Suppose that there exists a ring isomorphism $T\colon C(X)\to C(Y)$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $h\colon Y\to X$ such that $$Tf = f\circ h\text{ for all }f\in C(X).$$ In particular, $T$ is a continuous algebra isomorphism.

Click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/a-theorem-due-to-gelfand-and-kolmogorov) for some references. Actually there is a more general result due to Milgram which asserts that two compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic if and only if there exists a multiplicative bijection between $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$.

Comment: Not my field, but that looks like a very nice generalization.

Answer (score 5):

An algebra isomorphism of $C(X)$ to $C(Y)$ is automatically continuous in the norm, because $\|f\| = \sup \{|\lambda|: \lambda \in \sigma(f)\}$.  $F$ induces a homeomorphism of the maximal ideal spaces, and these are in turn homeomorphic to $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for answer the question, but I still a little bit confused on how to induce a homeomorphism.

Comment: Is your "automatically continuous" means "give any algebra isomorphism $\phi :C(X) →  C(Y)$, then $\phi$ is continuous."?

Comment: @yoyo, yes. It is actually automatically of the form $\phi(f)=f\circ h$, where $h$ is a homeomorphism. This is the content of the Gelfand-Kolmogorov theorem. See my post below.